# Google Calendar Calendar List, Event List

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-calendar-api

I am using GTMAppAuth SignIn for authentication in one of my iOS application. With that I am defining all possible scopes for Google Calendar use but still getting the following error.Google Calendar API &  CalDAV API is enable on Google Console but still I do not know why I am getting this error.i also add Scopes for Google APIs shown in below image.

[image]

```
my code is given below:


-(void) fetchCalendarList
 {
    self.calendarList = nil;
    self.calendarListFetchError = nil;

    id<GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol> authorization =
    [GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization authorizationFromKeychainForName:kGTMAppAuthKeychainItemName];

    self.calendarService.authorizer = authorization;
    GTLRCalendarService *service = self.calendarService;

    GTLRCalendarQuery_CalendarListList *query = [GTLRCalendarQuery_CalendarListList query];

//    query.minAccessRole = kGTLRCalendarMinAccessRoleOwner;
//  query.minAccessRole = kGTLRCalendarOrderByStartTime;


    self.calendarListTicket = [service executeQuery:query
                                  completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *callbackTicket,
                                                      id calendarList,
                                                      NSError *callbackError) {
                                      // Callback
                                      self.calendarList = calendarList;
                                      self.calendarListFetchError = callbackError;
                                      self.calendarListTicket = nil;
                                      [self fetchEvents];
                                  }];
}

 i am getting this error:

Printing description of callbackError:
Error Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=403 "Insufficient Permission" UserInfo={GTLRStructuredError=GTLRErrorObject 0x1c065adc0: {message:"Insufficient Permission" errors:[1] code:403}, NSLocalizedDescription=Insufficient Permission}
```

Comment: Could you provide the error logs?

Comment: yes, Error log is already given in above question. just last line.